# Limit point clarification

Tags: general-topology, advice

Proposition 3.1.6:
A is closed iff A contains its limit points

and the def of a limit point.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

I usually think closed sets have limit points
because of 3.1.6.
So l recently thought of open sets, and
found they do too.

If both open and closed sets have limit
points why is 3.1.6 useful?

Where is the defining difference in using
it

Ok . I thought more. An open set could have more outside the
set

Comment: Which book is the proposition from? How is "closed" defined?

Comment: Topology Without Tears. Standard def.

Comment: A is open X\A is closed. Compliment of A , A set that contains it boundaries. Or in interval terms A={a$\leq$x$\leq$b}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because while, indeed, usually open sets *have* limit poits, they do not contain *all* limit points.

Comment: Which is what I added. A closed set has all of them

Comment: Yes, that new sentence at the end is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between "having" limit points and "containing" them. An open interval $(0,1)$ has $0$ and $1$ as limit points, but they do not belong to the interval. For closed sets, their limit points belong to them.

Comment: Yup l know that.l was going to state that, but decided not too

Answer (score 0):

Proposition 3.1.6 is a characterization of closed sets. The original statement in the book (bold font mine):

> Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $(X,\tau)$. Then $A$ is closed in $(X,\tau)$ if and only if $A$ contains **all** of its limit points.

Your [book](https://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf) comment on the previous page of the proposition that

> "The next proposition provides a useful way of testing whether a set is closed or not."

and right after Proposition 3.1.6, it gives an example on how it is useful:

> [image]

Comment: Open sets don’t have all of them.All you need to do is find one outside it

Comment: @Homer: so is my answer useful for you?

Comment: Why a downvote ? If l ask dumb questions I seem to get penalized for it? Maybe they are too dumb ? https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-and-answer-them/

Comment: @Homer: I don't know about the downvote. But why do you leave this comment here? Did you want to leave it under your own question?

Comment: Yes.But you can’t upvote your own posting.l am aware of what you posted. When l posted my question about limit pt,l was thinking l was thinking if both sets have them what is the difference?  Is that a dumb question? ref: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-and-answer-them/

Comment: @Homer: I am well aware Terry Tao's post on "dumb questions". But you should not forget about a main part of the title "and answer them (on your own)".

Comment: @Homer: I am aware that you have asked quite a few questions on topology. But you have never accepted any answers. Do you know how to accept an answer?

Comment: I push the triangle icon.l assume that is what is accepted

Comment: @Homer: no, you need to click the "check mark" button $\checkmark$ in order to accept an answer. See details here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work